# 'c++' not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, c++

I have recently installed MinGW for Windows, and I am wanting to compile a program named `"object.cpp"` at `C:\Users\User\`. So I open the command prompt, go to my desired directory, and type in the command `c++ object.cpp`. I am expecting it to return with nothing, but then I receive the error message:

> 'c++' not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have tried Setting the Environmental Variable `Path` to `C:\MinGW\bin;` but it still comes up with the error message. What should I do to correct this?

**Edit:**

People have said I should use `g++` It still doesn't work.

Also, in `C:\MinGW\bin`, there exists a `c++` and `g++` `.exe` files. So, I do not know what is wrong.

The command prompt is displaying:

`C:\Users\User>c++
'c++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\User>g++
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\User>mingw
'mingw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output from running `path` in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: Stop running things in the Windows command prompt and launch MinGW first.  If that fails provide the full path to MinGW.  You have skipped an installation step.

Comment: @Ramhound You mean the installer?

Comment: No; There is a MinGW executable in the installation directory.  Provide the full path to the executables and the .cpp file in your above attempts

Comment: @Ramhound, all I see are a few folders in `C:\MinGW`

Comment: “in C:\MinGW\bin, there exists a c++ and g++ .exe files. So, I do not know what is wrong.” You said otherwise

Comment: @Ramhound I do not get you

Comment: The error you are getting means you need to use the full path to the executable and the file you want to compile because your system variable isn’t correct (if it was correct then the full path wouldn’t be required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ compiler that comes with GCC/MinGW uses the command "g++".

Comment: Nope, please read edit

Answer (score 2):

#### `c++` not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

That is because the name of the c++ compiler is `g++`.

> For those who are just starting out, this will explain how to use
>   MinGW to compile an executable, from C or C++ source, in a command
>   prompt environment.
>
> First you must make sure you have installed MinGW and set the PATH
>   environment variable include the location of MinGW; this is explained
>   Here.
>
> Now, assuming your directory for MinGW is the default "C:\MinGW", and
>   your PATH environment variable is set to include "C:\MinGW\bin", it is
>   easy to start compiling an executable:
>
> Open a command prompt window, and set the current directory to
>   wherever your *.c or *.cpp file is.
>
> Example:
>
> For the file helloworld.cpp in the folder C:\sources\hello enter the
>   commands
>
> ```
> cd c:\sources\hello
> ```
>
> Now type the compile command
>
> ```
> g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe
> ```
>
> The -o switch specifies the name of the output file, without it the
>   output file would be given a default name of "a.exe".

Source [MinGW for First Time Users HOWTO](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto)

Comment: @Goodra Then your path is wrong. Please read [HOWTO Install the MinGW (GCC) Compiler Suite](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite), [Getting Started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](//superuser.com/q/284342)